# R returning index elements

Tags: r

I have a matrix:

```
x<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),nrow=10,ncol=1)
```

and an index:

```
vec<-c(1,4,7,8,9,10)
```

I would like to get all the elements less than the next index. So in the above example given the above index vector, I would like to see something like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7
8
9
10
```

I am currently using a for loop:

```
for(i in 2:length(vec)){
  cat(x[(vec[i-1]):(vec[i]-1)],"\n")

}
```

This works great, but it doesn't return the last element, 10.

Any ideas?

Can someone try this example, my R session seems to be returning the wrong values:

```
vec<-c(1,7, 10, 11, 12)
x<- c(251, 272, 291, 314, 333, 355, 377, 397, 420, 440, 462, 483, 503)
```

Thanks,

Comment: The second version is completely different in that vec doesn't  have values in the range x.

Comment: I think that is supposed to be the result he's getting? Doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Possibly `vec` refers to the indices of `x`, not the values? @user1234440, please post the desired output for your second example.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tapply( x,  findInterval( x,  vec) ,'[')
```

If you want to use x[vec] as the break points then just use that as the second argument to findInterval.

Comment: I tested my edited answer on a vector since I was reasonably sure the results would be the same.

Comment: Your solution is a lot prettier than mine :)

Comment: would you mind testing my editted example at the bottom of the question? I know you are right, but dunno why I am getting a single return row...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lapply(1:length(vec)
   ,function(i){
     min_ix = vec[i]
     max_ix = vec[i+1]
     if(i<length(vec)){x[x<max_ix & x>=min_ix]}
     else{x[x>=min_ix]}
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using split and populating your `vec` with in-between values. If `vec` doesn't end with `length(x)` expect warnings (but still correct results):

```
split(x, rep(vec, c(diff(vec), 1)))
```